# find the dimension of $W.$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $W=\{p(B):p \text{ is a polynomial with real coefficients}\},$ where $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$ Then find the dimension of $W.$

I have shown $B^4=B$ and $c_1B+c_2B^2+c_3B^3=0\implies c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ and hence $\{B,B^2,B^3\}$ is a basis of $W.$ So $\dim W=3.$

Am I right?

Comment: 1 is also a polynomial.

Comment: @user73985: Yes, but here $B^3=I$ exactly.

Comment: you are really right